# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework: Determine Data Context Class from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm using the Entity Framework within an ASP.NET MVC Application and I would like to determine which Data Context Class and other Scaffolding options are associated with it. I know that if you add a new Controller to a project, you'll get an `Add Controller` dialog box that allows you to enter these values.

Since my Model, View and Controller are already created (This is a project that I inherited), is there a way within Visual Studio to determine the `Data Context Class`?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to determine the Data Context Class". If you have existing code, you can create instances of the context wherever you want. (As long as it's part of the assembly or its assembly is referenced, of course).

Comment: `using Example.Model` ? Please be more specific if you need a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered there are a couple of ReTrace tools that you can use to see how your MVC application is accessing Controllers, Views and Models.

1) [Stackify Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/): This is my preferred application since this will show you the sources of where your Data is generated (e.g. SQL Databases).

2) [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/): Another good, free ReTrace tool.